# CSS :not selector for divs within a div

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I want the Woocommerce add to cart button to look different on my homepage and on one other page.

I would like to do this:

```
    .add-to-cart-button-inner a:not(.home .add-to-cart-button-inner a, .page-132 .add-to-cart-button-inner a ) {
    some-css:here
    }
```

but Wordpress gives off an error.

Is there a working way to do this?

Comment: *"Wordpress gives off an error."* - Can you please edit your question to include the error?

Comment: thanks. the error just says - Unexpected token '(' . Not very useful, which is why I didn't mention it

Answer (score 4):

`:not()` is a pseudo selector and requires a [simple selector as an argument](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/). In your example, you are using a compound argument as your selector - likely the cause of your error.

Try something like:

```
.add-to-cart-button-inner a:not(.custom-selector-here) {
  background: red;
}
```

If you need more help, please provide more information about your error.